# How to check if a string field has only alphabets in BigQuery

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery

How to check if a string field in a BigQuery table has only alphabets and certain special characters like Å, Ä, and Ö in it? Any value with special characters or numbers should be avoided from selection.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function `REGEXP_CONTAINS` to perform this kind of selection:

```
SELECT
  text,
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, r"^[A-Za-zÅÄÖ]+$") AS is_selected
FROM
  `dataset.yourtable`
```

Here with the regex "^[A-Za-zÅÄÖ]+$" strings composed of only alphabet, Å, Ä or Ö will return `true`.

For instance with the `text` column below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Below is generic solution to account not just for Å, Ä, and Ö but for all such chars like ç,æ,œ,á,é,í,ó,ú,à,è,ì,ò,ù,ä,ë,ï,ö,ü,ÿ,â,ê,î,ô,û,å,ø,Ø,Å,Á,À,Â,Ä,È,É,Ê,Ë,Í,Î,Ï,Ì,Ò,Ó,Ô,Ö,Ú,Ù,Û,Ü,Ÿ,Ç,Æ,Œ,ñ etc.

```
select text
from `project.dataset.table`
where not regexp_contains(regexp_replace(normalize(text, NFD), r"\pM", ''), r'\W')
```

if applied to sample data provided by @Cylldby in his answer  - output is

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant ! Thank you I learned something, this is a much more exhaustive solution than mine. (I think @rr_coder doesn't want digits in his results so maybe [^a-zA-Z] would fit better than \W).

Comment: thank you @Cylldby - I think most of my answers tailored  in such a way that they not just answer the question with trivial solutions! I always try to add some spice into my answer and bring something new and not trivial. check them and let me know if you agree :o)